# How to update a property in Inertia.js and Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, inertiajs, es6-proxy

I am trying to update a property `list` in Vue.js using Inertia.js:

```js
props: {
    list: {
        type: Object, 
        default: {}
    }
},
```

```js
updateTable(filters) {
    axios.post(route('updateList'), filters)
        .then(r => {
            this.list = r.data
        })
}
```

But I get the following error: `TypeError: 'set' on proxy: trap returned falsish for property`

In Inertia.js, all props are provided as proxies. As described in [this mdn article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy/Proxy/set), the proxie's `set` method needs to return true to allow the assignment. However, I have no idea how to correctly achieve that as I do not create the proxy myself. Any suggestions?

Or is it that with Inertia I would always be forced to use a [partial reload](https://inertiajs.com/partial-reloads)?

Answer (score 1):

I believe there's some misunderstandings of Vue itself and how Inertia works here.

You're receiving the `list` as a prop. Props should not be directly changed.

If you ABSOLUTELY need to change it, you can reference it directly by `this.$page.props.list` instead of receiving the list as a prop.

Or, you can do this:

```js
export default {
   props: {
      list: {
         type: Object,
         default: {}
      }
   },
   data () {
      return {
         listCopy: this.list
      }
   },
   mounted () {
      // Handle your scroll events
      axios.get(this.listCopy.next_page_url).then(response => {
         this.listCopy = {
            ...response.data,
            data: [...this.listCopy.data, ...response.data.data]
         }
      })
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I get the point of killing the purpose of inertia. However, in this specific case it's about extending the list's content with an intersectionObserver when you've scroll to the end and I don't think that reloading would be the best way to do things here. That's why I would rather append to the original list instead.

Comment: Ok... I get it... I updated the answer... see if this is what you were looking for...